# Google API Developer: purchases.products.get is ignoring productId value and always returns 200

Tags: google-play, subscription, in-app

When call GET method on [https://www.googleapis.com/androidpublisher/v3/applications/{packageId}/purchases/subscriptions/{productId}/tokens/{token}](https://www.googleapis.com/androidpublisher/v3/applications/%7BpackageId%7D/purchases/subscriptions/%7BproductId%7D/tokens/%7Btoken%7D)
it is ignoring productId value and always returns 200, whether its the correct product id or not, previously it used to reutn an error if its not correct

Comment: how are you calling this? put the full code.

Comment: Actually there no need for code, use it cURL GET request

Answer (score 0):

There is an issue on Google bug-tracker: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/169870112